# PDF rendering in onenote

Tags: image, pdf, onenote

I am creating onenote pages using the microsoft graph api.  I try to display a pdf using the method found on the site  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-images-files#add-images-of-pdf-file-contents.  However, it comes only as an attachment and does not render the pdf, like if I did a printout insertion in onenote.  Has anyone encountered this and has anyone have some sample code if you did?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag to embed the PDF as an image is `<img data-render-src="name:FileBlock" />` (replace `name:FileBlock` with whatever the name of that form part is).